# Is there a way to let mockito generate mocks for integration tests in a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, mockito-dart

Mockito generates mocks for all classes listet within the `@GenerateMocks` annotatio. It does so for tests in the `test` folder but it doesn't for tests in the `integration_test` folder. How do I change that?

Comment: Felix Angelov (the author of `flutter_bloc`) made a dart package named `mocktail`, which uses most of mockito's API, but without the need to generate mock classes. https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## TL;DR

Add a build.yaml file with the following content to your project root folder.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      - $package$
      - lib/$lib$
      - lib/**.dart
      - test/**.dart
      - integration_test/**.dart
    builders:
      mockito|mockBuilder:
        generate_for:
          - test/**.dart
          - integration_test/**.dart
```

## Explanation

Both `generate_for` and `sources` are needed to tell the mockBuilder which files should be processed.

The `generate_for` configuration is only a subset of the all the files  used by the builder. But these files do not include the integration_test folder by default. To modify that, we can list the sources files manually. We have to include the default sources `$package$`and `lib/$lib$`, or we will get warnings if not.

By including any folder - in our case 'integration_test' it will then also be available to `generate_for`.

Here is the excerpt from the [build_config/README.md](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build_config/README.md):

- **generate_for**: List of String or Map, Optional:. The subset of files within
  the target's `sources` which should have this Builder applied. See `sources`
  configuration above for how to configure this.

and:

- **sources**: List of Strings or Map, Optional. The set of files within the
  package which make up this target. Files are specified using glob syntax. If a
  List of Strings is used they are considered the 'include' globs. If a Map is
  used can only have the keys `include` and `exclude`. Any file which matches
  any glob in `include` and no globs in `exclude` is considered a source of the
  target. When `include` is omitted every file is considered a match.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on [HerrJohr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68275812/3302026):

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      include:
        - $package$
        - lib/$lib$
        - lib/**
        - test/**
        - integration_test/**
    builders:
      mockito|mockBuilder:
        generate_for:
          include:
            - test/**
            - integration_test/**
```

See more:

1. Default `sources` - [build/build_runner_core/lib/src/generate
   /options.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/3087308cd3649e83057155b1995a206527bb7028/build_runner_core/lib/src/generate/options.dart#L37)
2. "How can I include additional sources in my build?" from [build/docs/faq.md](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/3087308cd3649e83057155b1995a206527bb7028/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-include-additional-sources-in-my-build)
3. Default `generate_for` - [mockito/build.yaml](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/afa20a80ef3147845fc78c80ace9d66f0ceb0453/build.yaml#L17)